# Не могу получить значение инпута в битрикс 1с

Tags: ajax, битрикс

Всем доброго дня. Возникла следующая проблема. Я не могу получить значение инпута. Работаю в битрикс 1с.   console.log(name)-ничего не выводит. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
<form action="" method="post">
      <input  type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg inn" id="name" placeholder="" value="" >
         <button id="button" type="submit">e</button>
   </form>
      <div class="errors_container"></div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suggestions-jquery@20.3.0/dist/css/suggestions.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/suggestions-jquery@20.3.0/dist/js/jquery.suggestions.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      
         $("#button").on("click",function(){
         var name=$("#iname").val();
        
        console.log(name);
      });
        
      BX.ajax({
           url: '/local/components/aaccent/order/component.php',
           data: {'name':name},
           method: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           timeout: 30,
           async: true,
           processData: true,
           scriptsRunFirst: true,
           emulateOnload: true,
           start: true,
           cache: false,
           onsuccess: function(data){
            console.log(data);
           },
           onfailure: function(){

           }
          }); 
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Опечатка в строке получения значения value по id: `var name=$("#name").val()`